# How to construct explicitly defining polynomials of an morphism between smooth irreducible curves?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, abelian-varieties, isogenies

Let $\phi\!: C_1 \to C_2$ be a separable morphism of smooth irreducible curves embedded as projectively normal models by invertible sheaves $\mathcal{L}_1$ and $\mathcal{L}_2$ respectively. Theorem 4.1 of [Kohel's article](https://books.google.fr/books?hl=ru&lr=&id=gc98CAAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA95&dq=The%20geometry%20of%20efficient%20arithmetic%20on%20elliptic%20curves&ots=xAShzVivra&sig=QszgPiZtNgjdoWGlIp_bGO_F398&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=The%20geometry%20of%20efficient%20arithmetic%20on%20elliptic%20curves&f=false) (cf. [Lange's article](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01450080.pdf)) claims that the morphism $\phi$ can be given by a complete tuple $\mathfrak{s} = (f_0, \cdots\!, f_r)$ of defining polynomials of degree $n \in \mathbb{N}$ if (and only if) $\phi^*\mathcal{L}_2 \simeq \mathcal{L}_1^n$. In the proof of the theorem it is said that the tuple $\mathfrak{s}$ corresponds to an element of the one-dimensional vector space
$$
\mathrm{Hom}(\phi^*\mathcal{L}_2, \mathcal{L}_1^n) \simeq \Gamma(C_1, \phi^*\mathcal{L}_2^{-1} \otimes \mathcal{L}_1^n).
$$
Suppose that I know a non-zero rational function from the right space. How to construct explicitly the corresponding tuple $\mathfrak{s}$ ?

In fact, I am interested in the case when $\phi$ is a cyclic isogeny of odd degree (with the given kernel $G$) between elliptic curves $C_1$, $C_2$ in the Weierstrass form, $n=1$, and $\mathcal{L}_1$, $\mathcal{L}_2$ correspond to the divisors $3\deg(\phi)\mathcal{O}$ and $3\mathcal{O}$ respectively, where $\mathcal{O} := (0:1:0)$. It is easily seen that the condition $\phi^*\mathcal{L}_2 \simeq \mathcal{L}_1^n$ is met, because $\#G = \deg(\phi)$ and the sum of points from $G$ is zero.